# ASP.NET 4 GridView - Pulling a Hyperlink out of a Database

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView bound to a SqlDataSource.

I'm pulling hyperlinks which point to Job Descriptions stored in a separate web space, out of a database and placing them in the GridView.

These are full Hyperlinks such as "Http://stackoverflow.com/"

Originally the GridView column was a simple BoundField like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="JobDescription" HeaderText="JobDescription" 
    SortExpression="JobDescription" />
```

So I started trying to convert it into a hyperlink field.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="JobDescription"
    DataTextField="JobDescription" 
    HeaderText="JobDescription"
    SortExpression="JobDescription" 
    Target="_blank" 
    NavigateUrl="{0}" />
```

This produced the desired result, but I can no longer edit that column in the GridView.  When it was a BoundField I could edit the item, but could find no way to make it into a hyperlink.

Either way will work...

I either need the HyperLinkField to be updatable, or I need the BoundField to be formatted as a Hyperlink with what it pulls directly from the database.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: I tried something on Microsofts website.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Still didn't enable me to edit the data in the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grrr found the answer:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="JobDescription" HeaderText="Job Description" 
    SortExpression="JobDescription" 
    DataFormatString="<a target='_blank' href='{0}'>Text</a>" 
    HtmlEncode="False" />
```

You don't need a template field.  That HtmlEncode property must be set to false in order for html in DataFormatString to be rendered as html, otherwise it changes all of your characters into the equivalent of stuff like...

```
&nbsp;
```

The Entity Numbers here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Template Field](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs). So your can define your normal view and [editing view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.edititemtemplate.aspx).